# NSPredicate contains search in a collection <SKTPackage>

Tags: uitableview, ios7, nspredicate, uisearchdisplaycontroller, skmaps

I am using SKMaps in my project which is used to download offline maps and I have to use NSPredicatefor search through some collection of SKTPackage.

To display name of the country I am reading "en" value like this

```
cell.textLabel.text = [package nameForLanguageCode:@"en"];
```

Now I want to search name of the country from the list. Now to do so I am using following line of code

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"en contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];
```

but it is giving me a crash with following message

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection  (not a collection)'.

Please suggest me what is the correct way of searching this this key using NSPredicate.

Comment: What is SKTPackage ?

Comment: Please see the edit. Its a class in SDKTool framework,

Answer (score 1):

You can search for a country in an array of countries you have already populated using the following lines of codes:

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", @“countryName”];
    NSArray *results = [countries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];